# Best use of the 'separation' and 'stage-separation' tags

Tags: discussion, tags

- [separation](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/separation)  11 questions
- [stage-separation](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stage-separation) 14 questions
- [both tags](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stage-separation+separation): no questions at the moment

The meaning of `stage-separation` is probably straightforward, but what are all of the types of things for which `separation` would apply?

I can imagine booster and fuel-tank separations would count, but what about

- capsule separation as in [Why does Blue Origin land the crew capsule separate from the booster?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18885/12102) (stage, or no-stage?)
- use of the `separation` tag in the question [What is the closest intentional separation achieved by two satellites?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19383/12102)

Should a Wiki excerpt be added to make sure it is for non-stage-separation-based separations? What should it say exactly, and what to do about capsules?

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the fact that you pointed out that not all separations may be considered related to staging, there is another implicit difference I see between these two terms--may not always be there but is definitely sometimes implied. "Stage separation" describes a process, whereas "separation" is a single event.

That said, I'm not clear on how we should define usage of these tags, but we do need to establish their usage guidelines and probably retag some questions.